# All.js broken? has no method 'addMonths'

Tags: javascript, facebook

Seeing a JS error that started today coming from all.js - has no method 'addMonths'

[image: console log error]

Did a recent push break this?

[image: relevant function call]

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug on Facebook tracking the issue here. I assume the more responses the faster it will get addressed:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/149848578458727

Answer (score 2):

Add the following before you call `FB.init`:

```
Date.prototype.addMonths = function(n){
    this.setMonth(this.getMonth()+n);
    return this;
}
```